# NFC implementation tizen wearable

Tags: nfc, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

Unable to get NDEFRecordsText.text from tizen NFC simulator. Am only getting first three characters.

Is it a bug from simulator or am i doing something wrong ?

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
var setPeerDetect = {
            /* When an NFC tag is detected */
            onattach: function(nfcPeer) {
                
                nfcPeer.setReceiveNDEFListener(function(ndefMessage){
                    console.log(ndefMessage.records[0].text);   
                    return true;
                });
            },

            /* When an NFC tag becomes unavailable */
            ondetach: function() {
                console.log('NFC Peer unavailable');
            }
        };
```

Here, ndefMessage.records[0].text just returns first three characters of payload. Also how can i decode the actual payload sent through emulator, currently am getting something like [5,121,121,0,0,0,0] as payload from ndefRecord

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you seem to use some custom field of NDEFRecord interface which is defined [here](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/5.5/device_api/mobile/tizen/nfc.html#NDEFRecord).
'*text*' member is not defined in documentation. To access payload of message, you just need to use:

```
console.log(ndefMessage.records[0].payload);
```

I quickly confirmed this on Tizen 6.0 wearable emulator available in Tizen Studio 4.1, which I have installed.